# TeXmaker: Change interface fonts

Tags: texmaker, mac

I am a newbie to Mac OS X. I installed TeXmaker and found that the Chinese characters in the interface are garbled completely (see figure below).
[image]

I tried a lot to fix this but nothing worked. Finally I realized that this is related to the "**Interface fonts**". However, on my mac there's no such setting option!!! (Previously I used ArchLinux and there was indeed such a button)

Does someone happen to know how to modify "**interface fonts**" for mac TeXmaker? Many thanks in advance!